# About setbinding in canvas

Tags: wpf

`<StackPanel Height="650" Width="650" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl Name="Display_Test" Margin="10">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Black" Width="600" Height="600"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Margin="15" Height="500" Width="500"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>`

// c# code start ====================================================================
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

```
        Canvas canvasSample = new Canvas();
        canvasSample.Width = 100;
        canvasSample.Height = 100;
        canvasSample.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
        CanvasList.Add(canvasSample);

        Canvas canvasSample2 = new Canvas();
        canvasSample2.Width = 100;
        canvasSample2.Height = 100;
        canvasSample2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);

        CanvasList.Add(canvasSample2);

        Rectangle rectangleSample = new Rectangle();
        rectangleSample.Width = 30;
        rectangleSample.Height = 30;
        RectangleList.Add(rectangleSample);

        Rectangle rectangleSample2 = new Rectangle();
        rectangleSample2.Width = 30;
        rectangleSample2.Height = 30;
        RectangleList.Add(rectangleSample2);

        Display_Test.ItemsSource = CanvasList;

        this.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainWindow_MouseDoubleClick);
    }

    void MainWindow_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int nCanvasNum = 0; nCanvasNum < CanvasList.Count; nCanvasNum++)
        {
            Binding conBinding = new Binding()
            {
                Source = RectangleList
            };
            CanvasList[nCanvasNum].DataContext = RectangleList;
            CanvasList[nCanvasNum].SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, conBinding);
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Canvas> _canvasList = new ObservableCollection<Canvas>();
    public ObservableCollection<Canvas> CanvasList
    {
        get { return _canvasList; }
        set
        {
            _canvasList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanvasList"));
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Rectangle> _rectangleList = new ObservableCollection<Rectangle>();
    public ObservableCollection<Rectangle> RectangleList
    {
        get { return _rectangleList; }
        set
        {
            _rectangleList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RegtangleList")); 
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

// c# code end ====================================================================

when i clicked mousebutton double I want to create RectangleList in CanvasList...
But I'm afraid I can't show that...I think that is problem because of setbinding...
I will wait for your answer....

Answer (score 0):

`CanvasList[nCanvasNum].SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, conBinding);` won't work bevause Canvas is not derived from ItemsControl and does not have ItemSource property. It has children property but it is not dependency property so you can't bind to it but you can add childrens manually. You can try to use ItemsControl instead of Canvas and set Canvas as a panel for ItemsControl the same way you did it to Show canvases

Comment: You can try to use ItemsControl instead of Canvas and set Canvas as a panel for ItemsControl the same way you did it to Show canvases
==> I don't understand...I have many canvas...But you tole me Canvas and set Canvas as a panel for ItemsControl....?
for exmaple)
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <Canvas ...>                   <== Your menas????

    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

Comment: Go step by step. Replace your CanvasList with ItemsControlList and see if your binding to RectanglesList works. Then work with ItemsControlList panel to get desired appearance

Comment: Ok, I got it...But I need to setbinding
So, I added DependencyProperty then changed MainWindow_MouseDoubleClick

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RectangleList", typeof(ObservableCollection<Rectangle>), typeof(MainWindow), null);

MainWindow_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Binding conBinding = new Binding()
            {
                Source = RectangleList,
            };

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(CanvasList[0], MainWindow.ItemsProperty, conBinding);            
        }